# Fix for "Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MovieService."

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-config

I keep getting this error but don't know why. If anyone could help me solve it, that would make my day

> Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the MovieService (?). Please make sure that the argument MovieRepository at index [0] is available in the MovieService context.

This is the structure of my MovieService:

```
import {Injectable} from "@nestjs/common";
import {InjectRepository} from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import {Repository} from "typeorm";
import {CreateMovieDto} from "./dto/create-movie.dto";
import {Movie} from "./movie.entity";

@Injectable()
export class MovieService {
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(Movie)
        private readonly movieRepository: Repository<Movie>
    ) {}
    create(createMovieDto: CreateMovieDto): Promise<Movie> {
        const movie = new Movie();
        movie.path = createMovieDto.path;
        movie.title = createMovieDto.title;
        movie.originalTitle = createMovieDto.originalTitle;
        movie.poster = createMovieDto.poster;
        movie.descr = createMovieDto.descr;
        movie.year = createMovieDto.year;

        return this.movieRepository.save(movie);
    }

    async findAll(): Promise<Movie[]> {
        return this.movieRepository.find();
    }

    findOne(id: string): Promise<Movie> {
        return this.movieRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    findByPath(path: string): Promise<Movie> {
        return this.movieRepository.findOne({path});
    }

    async remove(id: string): Promise<void> {
        await this.movieRepository.delete(id);
    }
}
```

The MovieModule :

```
import {Module} from "@nestjs/common";
import {TypeOrmModule} from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import {Movie} from "./movie.entity";
import {MovieService} from "./movie.service";

@Module({
    imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Movie])],
    providers: [MovieService],
    exports: [MovieService],
})
export class MovieModule {}
```

The Movie entity :

```
import {Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn} from "typeorm";

@Entity()
export class Movie {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column()
    path: string;

    @Column()
    title: string;

    @Column()
    originalTitle: string;

    @Column()
    poster: string;

    @Column()
    descr: string;

    @Column()
    year: string;
}
```

And the app module :

```
import {Module} from "@nestjs/common";
import {TypeOrmModule} from "@nestjs/typeorm";
import {AppController} from "./app.controller";
import {AppService} from "./app.service";
import {MovieModule} from "./movie/movie.module";

@Module({
    imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
            type: "mysql",
            host: "localhost",
            port: 3306,
            username: "*****",
            password: "*****",
            database: "*****",
            autoLoadEntities: true,
            synchronize: true,
        }),
        MovieModule,
    ],
    controllers: [AppController],
    providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

## Edit 1

I tried copy-pasting the movie folder into a new nest project and it works. I'm even more confused on why I get this error

Here's my package.json

```
{
  "name": "marineris",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.5",
    "hbs": "^4.1.2",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "sync-request": "^6.1.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.38",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.2",
    "eslint": "^7.30.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.6",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: your code looks fine to me. Try this: add `entites: [Movie]` to your `TypeOrmModule.forRoot` (even tho you're using `autoLoadEntities: true`)

Comment: I tried adding `entities: [Movie],` but I get the same error sadly

Comment: After reading your "Edit 1", it might have something with the packages you use, can you paste you `package.json` ?

Comment: I put it in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I messed up my imports/exports in some of the files of the project and after double-checking them it worked.